# reading xsl file from document library sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

I know it cud be quite simple questions for most of you. But I am not able to load xsl file from sharepoint document library.

i m trying to do this

```
getXSL = Server.MapPath("//Documents/myxsl.xslt");

  XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();


         xslt.Load(getXSL);
```

but if i m doing like this it is taking it as inetpub/wss/VirtualDirectories/80....
I want it to refer to my Document library where i have uploaded my xslt.Any one is having idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the SharePoint API to access the document library, not the standard ASP.NET object model.

You'd want something like (assuming you are running this from a web part, and have an SPContext object handy)

```
SPFile spXslt = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Documents"].Items["myxsl.xslt"].File;
```

From here you can stream the contents of the SPFile and use it with the XML object model.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this...
I tried yours and then added this 
Stream feedXSL = spXslt.OpenBinaryStream();
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
         xslt.Load(getXSL);

But its showing error.....

Comment: There are basicaly two errors....one 
Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Load(System.Xml.XmlReader)' has some invalid arguments 

Error 4 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.Xml.XmlReader' 


Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.this[int]' has some invalid arguments 
Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'int' 


These errors in your 2 lines....